# How to achieve this filter/action shown that will give the my pictures a cinematic/lively feel in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects, photo-editing, actions, filter, photography

The attached pictures below show two sample of the filter/effect that I want to achieve in Adobe Photoshop. Is this done through a Photoshop action or there is a particular set of steps that will lead to the effect in question? I tried achieving this by using a combination of brightness, levels, vibrance , saturation and etc but to no avail. **(image showing the original and target indicates what I'm trying to achieve)** [image: image showing the original and target indicates what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the image to a Smart Object, then apply the Adobe Camera Raw filter, and adjust the Basic settings as shown here:

[image]

Then go into Effects, and add a slight vignette like this:

[image]

Comment: Why a Smart Object? Just so you can change your mind without having to start over?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, because using ACR  as a filter on a Smart Object is non destructive, so it can be tweaked later if desired.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to get into that habit, it will save time long-term. It's one I've kind of just ignored/not bothered with, ever since it arrived.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah I find it a very useful feature.  You can also layer up multiple filters once you  have a Smart Object, even add distortions/transforms non-destructively. You can also open and edit the Smart Object by double clicking the layer thumbnail, maybe do some retouching on the original, save and close the Smart Object, and the filters you added are still applied. It's great for making editable/reusable templates too. So many possibilities.

Comment: Hi Billy, I followed the steps you provided and it worked like magic! Thanks for providing the essential steps such as converting to smart object as well, appreciate it!